# Can you integrate an "externally" coded react app into a Visual Studio project / workflow?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm working with a team that builds an application through a Visual Studio workflow as part of an Azure setup (Azure DevOps + Azure Repo) - the frontend of the application is intended to be a React application.

In this setup, I'm currently forced to code the Frontend using Visual Studio, as any code or file change done outside of Visual Studio is not recognized by Visual Studio and cannot be committed or pushed. This is an impossible setup for a multitude of reasons.

How can I:

- Code a React Frontend using Visual Studio **Code** offset from the Visual Studio project?
- Integrate this React Frontend back into the Visual Studio project so it can be deployed?

Simply copying the source folder of a React App *not created in Visual Studio* into a Visual Studio project throws an infinite amount of errors, making me assume that such an operation is deliberately prohibited and Visual Studio requires an application to be "made from one piece".

Can this be bypassed somehow?

Comment: Nothing prohibits doing things outside, nothing prohibits you from editing files in any editor and committing them, this would need a lot more info about how things are set up. I constantly edit with different programs in the same repo, that’s not a problem with any version control tool. So what errors exactly are shown and from what?

Comment: Yes, I'm free to edit any file within the project as I like. However, IF this change is NOT done through Visual Studio the change is simply not recognized:

- I change a *.JS File in Visual Studio Code. The change won't show up in Visual Studio unless I conduct this very change through Visual Studio itself.

- I create a new folder in Finder. This new folder won't show up in Visual Studio unless it's created in Visual Studio.

- I delete a file / folder via Terminal. This deletion will not show up in Visual Studio unless deleted in Visual Studio.

Comment: „Prohibit" refers to the ability to just copy+paste a React Application coded without using Visual Studio into a Visual Studio project.

Comment: How does it not show up exactly? What’s the structure of the project? Old style? Then just add the files/folders to the project afterwards if they need to be there. Why does it need to show up in the project if it’s a separate front end part? Does VS compile it? And Finder? So is this VS *for Mac*, which is very different software.

Comment: I think I can be't more precise than described above. I can edit, change or remove any file with any tool I want and that change is visible to every tool on my device. Except for Visual Studio (Running as Windows version on a VM) that  only recognizes changes done through Visual Studio itself.  I delete a file - it' s deleted for every other application. Visual Studio will still list this file in the file overview on both my machine and the repo (still being there on the repo is logical).

Comment: I need to make a minimum of one change to be able to commit. I delete a file using Windows Explorer. I'm still unable to make a commit as Visual Studio does not recognize the file deletion. I edit a JS file through VIsual Studio Code or a texteditor: the edit is visible in every tool. In Visual Studio the change is inivisble and I can't commit as Visual Studio doesn't recognize any file change.